# How to save a PDF of a textarea with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I'm working on a simple text editor with a save button that converts the text in a textarea to PDF on the user's computer. I've tried two libraries: Fountain.js and jsPDF. Neither worked. (I tried both linking through a CDN and using a local, downloaded version.)

I've been working on this for about 9 hours, troubleshooting for most of that time. I've tried a pure JS method as well, which downloaded the file, but without the internal PDF structure, so you can't open the file. I've done a lot of googling, a ton of prompting on Bard, and read several similar questions here on Stack Overflow, and I always get the same few errors in the console, and no files.

I've started over on this seemingly simple project about six times, and at this point I'm beginning to get confused.

Any suggestions as to how to save the value of a textarea as a PDF that actually works? I'll work on formatting after I get this basic functionality down. Any help would be appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" href="styles.css">
        <script type="module" src="jspdf.es.min.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="screenplay-container">
            <textarea class="screenplay-text" id="screenplay-text"></textarea>
            <button id="save-button">Save as PDF</button>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf.es.min.js';

const doc = new jsPDF();

const saveButton = document.getElementById('save-button');

saveButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const doc = new jsPDF();
  const screenplayText = document.getElementById('screenplay-text').value;
  doc.text(screenplayText, 10, 10);
  doc.save('screenplay.pdf');
});
```

Simple, yet infuriating. Here are my current error messages:

```
ERROR: GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

ERROR: index.html:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

ERROR: scripts.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at scripts.js:1:1)

ERROR: index.html:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

[Screenshot of my simple textarea project and current errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYLcI.jpg)

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Please provide file tree information

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the slow response. As for the file tree, all the files are in the same folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lengua/qs9u530j/) that works

You can do it like this:

Import jsPDF from `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js`

Your HTML:

```
<div class="screenplay-container">
  <textarea class="screenplay-text" id="screenplay-text">Something written here</textarea>
  <button id="save-button">Save as PDF</button>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
const doc = new jsPDF();

const saveButton = document.getElementById('save-button');

saveButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const screenplayText = document.getElementById('screenplay-text').value;
  
  doc.setFontSize(16);
  doc.text(screenplayText, 10, 10);
  // Set the document to automatically print via JS
  //doc.autoPrint();
  // Or force download
  doc.save('screenplay.pdf');
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked, and you have saved my butt, @Sanxofon! Have a great day!